# OkHttpClient throws an error when trying to load data from sharedPrefrences

Tags: java, android, http, okhttp, esp32

I'm making an app that controls esp modules and I'm using OkHttpClient to make post web requests.
You can set the ip of the esp module in the settings tab(e.g. if your esp ip is 123.456.789, the url for web request would be http://123.456.789), I'm saving, loading and getting that data from my settings activity to my main activity using sharedPrefrences, but when I open the app, it just crashes with the error url == null.

The only way I got it to work would be if I load it something like this:

```
public String ip = SettingsActivity.ipEsp;
```

but then every time I re-open the app, I have to open the setting activity for the data to be loaded.(tried saving this value with sharedPrefrences, but it doesn't seem to work, it doesn't crash or anything it just doesn't work)

I would want to have it saved in a way so whenever I re-open the app, it remembers the ip address that i set in the settings.

Here's the main activity code:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button settings;
    Button send;
    TextView view;
    TextView see;
    public String urlS;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        see = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.see);

        SharedPreferences urls = getSharedPreferences("sPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

        urlS = urls.getString("url", "http://0.0.0.0:8888");





        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            client.newCall(requestlL).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()){
                        String myR = response.body().string();

                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                see.setText(myR);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

                view.setText(urlS);
            }




        }
        );


        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            setting();
            }
        });



    }


    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    String urllL = urlS;

    Request requestlL = new Request.Builder()
            .url(urllL)
            .build();


    public void setting() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

and this is the setting activity code:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

private Handler sHand = new Handler();
public static final String S_PREFS = "sPrefs";
public static final String URL = "url";

Button back;
Button save;
EditText url;


public String urlS;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    url = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);


    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            back();
        }
    });


    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            urlS = url.getText().toString();
            save();

        }
    });


    load();
    view();



}

public void back()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}




public void saveDataRunS()
{
    sHand.post(saveDs);
}

private Runnable saveDs= new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        save();
        load();

        sHand.postDelayed(this, 1);


    }

};





public void save()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();

    edit.putString(URL, url.getText().toString());

    edit.apply();
}

public void load()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(S_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    urlS = sharedPreferences.getString(URL, "http://0.0.0.0:8888");

}

public void view()
{
    url.setText(urlS);

}
```

}

and this is the error i get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.test, PID: 18146
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: url == null
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3222)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3437)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2041)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7386)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: url == null
    at okhttp3.Request$Builder.url(Request.java:132)
    at com.example.test.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:99)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1250)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3210)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3437) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2041) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7386) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
```

Comment: Frankly, that's way more code than anyone here is likely to actually look at.

You should create a small example that just illustrates the problem. This will likely allow you to discover the source of the problem yourself too. 

It seems like the problem has nothing to do with http client, and everything to do with storing and retrieving shared prefs. 

So, my suggestion - write a separate, sample app that just stores and retrieves shared prefs. Once you have that working, put that code into your main app.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I made an app as you suggested, but the same error occurs, also I have updated my post with an example app so it has less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@leeo6002
In MainActivity2, save() method is called in the following fashion.
onCreate -> saveDataRunS ->sHand.post(saveDs) -> save -> edit.putString(URL, url.getText().toString());

Basically, you are fetching the value from the url editText as soon as activity's onCreate is triggered. Which means you are not waiting for the user to enter the value in the EditText. At least, this is one of the issue.

Honestly, You need to clean up your code, It is a lot of mess right now.

Comment: I changed it so the save() method is called only when the save button is pressed and I edited the post with changes i made to the code, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Try putting the following code inside onClick of send button in MainActivity. method to narrow down the issue
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    String urllL = urlS;

    Request requestlL = new Request.Builder()
            .url(urllL)
            .build();

Comment: Ok, that works and solves half of my problem since in my original code, there's a function that is constantly running to read the data from the web server so I can't build the url with a button click.